# Is there a way to append to an external blend file?

Tags: python

I know that `bpy.data.libraries.load()` allows me to append data from an external file to my current blender instance, but is there a way to do the reverse? Take something (let's say the default cube) and append it to an external file using the Python?

My exact need is to take a node group from the current blend file, and append it to an external blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blender 2.78, [`bpy.data.libraries.write()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html#bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.write) will be an option to use, which will allow any datablock from the blend file to be saved to an external blend file.